# Calculation in Acrobat DC form using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, acrobat, calculation

I'm a novice at using JS, but using Acrobat DC to build registration form for a small conference, which requires using the Custom Javascript calculation option. Would like to use a check box to indicate an option to use a credit card as a method of payment, which would impose a 3% "convenience fee" onto the total payment amount, yielding a new total amount owed.

In my form, the total amount owed if paying by check is named "TA1."  Where I want the convenience fee amount (TA1 + 3%) is named "TA2." The checkbox is named "CheckBox6."  Based on scouring the net for a solution, tried using the following javascript in calculation tab of the field "TA2.":

```
if (this.getField("Check Box6").value != "Off") {
// box is checked
event.value = (this.getField(“TA1”).value+(this.getField(“TA1”).value*.03) ;
} else {
// box is unchecked
event.value = 0 ;}
```

Don't know if the scripting is correct otherwise, but I get an error saying the "}else{" line has an illegal character.  Why is there an illegal character and how can I get the correct final display?

Answer (score 0):

When you copied and pasted the code, there are curly quotes where the should be straight ones. The revised code below should work.

```
if (this.getField("Check Box6").value != "Off") {
    // box is checked
    event.value = this.getField("TA1").value + (this.getField("TA1").value * .03);
}
else {
    // box is unchecked
    event.value = 0;
}
```

Get yourself a decent code editor like Visual Studio Code. it would highlight these mistakes for you. You can then copy and paste the clean code into the Acrobat code editor.

Comment: Thank you for the help and recommendation.  Your edit cleared the error issue,